# TERM value for Windows 10 terminal

Tags: windows-10, terminal

What is the proper or closest TERM environment variable value that covers the Windows 10 command line/terminal window?

Answer (score 3):

For the traditional *Conhost* console window (native Windows 10), there is no ncurses terminfo definition at all. As of current Windows 10 versions, it is *somewhat* xterm-compatible.

For the *Windows Terminal* app (available through Store or GitHub), latest ncurses versions have `ms-terminal`, although the app is Xterm-compatible because pretty much everyone uses `xterm`/`xterm-256color`/`xterm-direct` anyway.